# Android How to get the public tweets with out making user login

Tags: android, android-studio, android-twitter

I know this question is asked already . I have read the twitter api. and its Aut but I am so dumb in understanding it.  So below is the key point what I want

What I want

1. I want to get all the tweets going on the basis of hash tag following is the example of what I want on mobile [Tweets on #Wwe](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23WWE&src=typd)
2. I want that my user should not have to sign in his/her twitter account. He just see the list of tweets in my app and get him self updated.

Please tell me which auth do I need ?
and How to do all these stuff. And good link with out twitter login please??

Answer (score 0):

**Steps for Authentication with Twitter Application**

1.Create an app on **twitter developer** account Create **Twitter App** Get
    **Consumer Key (API Key)** Some key value **Consumer Secret (API Secret)**
Some Secret Key Value

2.After getting key you require Bearer Key for
    Calling **Rest Api of Twiiter** https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token  
    Call this url from your android and you will get response as
    `{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAA%2FAAA%3DAAAAAAAA"}`
For
    more information [post/oauth2/token](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token) For getting usertimeline tweets
    json data call this url from android and pass bearer key as header 
**Authorization: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA**

You will get
    response decode it and display it. For search tweets by hashtag you
    have to call
    https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"+"?q="+URLEncoder.encode("#"+query,"UTF-8")+"&result_type=recent
    this rest api from android and in header bearer key  For detailed
    Application Only

**Your app will be able to, for example:**

1. Pull user timelines;
2. Access friends and followers of any account;
3. Access lists resources;
4. Search in tweets;
5. Retrieve any user information;

**And it won’t be able to:**

1. Post tweets or other resources;
2. Connect in Streaming endpoints;
3. Search for users;
4. Use any geo endpoint;
5. Access DMs or account credentials;

For more Details [Application only twiiter guide](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only)

Comment: I do not want to Pull user timelines;
Access friends and followers of any account;
Access lists resources; I just want to pull public tweets on hash tag

Comment: ya you may acces public tweets for hashtag,friends and followers using twitter search/list service.

Comment: For more information check out this check response you will get list of tweets searched/entered in json. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: you wiil get all tweets for  #Wwe using https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets service.

Comment: girri I know these things , But I want to ask how I would use these keys , ? How I would hit URL to get the tweets data ? 
Is it just same as we always do to get response from server ? please share that code

Comment: in both pages I didnt see where and when I would use those consumer key and secreat key , I want to know about calls that I have to made in according to get the tweets response

Comment: You need consumer and secret key for only getting bearer key. For getting response using autentication application you need to pass bearer key in header and q=#hashtag as value to that search service.

Comment: here i have done this https://github.com/maheshgiri/SimpleTwitterApp/blob/master/MyTwitterApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/hungry/myapplication/SearchTweetActivity.java        qurey value is hashtag value like hack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102588/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-mahesh-giri).

Comment: which project need to run , in you project given in the link , there are one more project in the main project    SimpleTwitterApp-Master it has only single mainActivity and in that project there is another project named MyTwitter app

Comment: @CoasMckey dude, did you made that work? just with hashtags?